# Github GraphQL API Authentication

Tags: json, github, async-await, graphql, fetch-api

I want to retrieve data from github's graphql api but I keep getting error message:
`{ message: 'This endpoint requires you to be authenticated.', documentation_url: 'https://docs.github.com/v3/#authentication' }`
Despite using a token, I even generated a new token to see if the other one was broken. The script to fetch the data can be found at https://repl.it/@DukeSanmi/AcrobaticModernLanguage#index.js
What could be the issue?

Answer (score 5):

Okay you need to put a space between `bearer` and your `variables.githubToken` like so:

```
const headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'bearer ' + variables.githubToken
};
```

Furthermore, **NEVER** publish secrets/credentials like API tokens in public code!

Comment: Thank you I already saw it and fix but I have another issue I hope you can help me with. I am trying to render the dominant language for each repository and its color(as an icon) and the last time the repository was updated. It is rendering icons for all the prog languages used in each repo instead of just the one with the largest file and the last update is not even rendering at all. What I'm I doing wrong? The code can be found here: https://repl.it/@DukeSanmi/ImpassionedScrawnySdk#script.js  (please excuse the messy)